# Getting Content-Type application/xml instead of text/xml when I send request through WSO MI

Tags: header, wso2, httprequest, content-type

Hi I am trying to send a request with header content-type as text/xml but I am getting application/xml.

wire logs are as follows:

```
DEBUG {header} - >> "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
```

The code I have used to make content-type text/xml is as follows:

```
1. <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="text/xml"/>
2. <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="text/xml"/>
```

I have used both of these lines both resulted in application/xml. How to ensure the content-type is text/xml instead of application/xml ?

Any help would mean a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following property.

```xml
<property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: can you please guide difference between contentType and messageType

Comment: When the message is sent out it goes through a process called message formatting. So this property tells wso2 which message formatter to use. In your case, it tells to use the text/xml message formatter. Once the message is formatted the content type will be set according to the message formatter it uses.